# Gaussian prime proof

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Prove or disprove that if $a+bi$ is a Gaussian prime, where a and b are nonzero, then $N(a+bi)$ is a rational prime.

I am pretty sure that there is a theorem that states this, but I'm not sure how to prove it.

Comment: You could always search for it before asking. I did it this time for you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer

Answer (score 1):

How about trying some examples?  How about $3$?  How about $1+i$?  How about $2+i$?  How about $3+2i$?  How about $7$?  These are all Gaussian primes... which you should check, also.

Don't be allergic to numbers.  Numbers are your friends!